# iPhone to iPhone communication

Tags: iphone, network-programming

I have been looking into communication methods between two iPhone devices and as I understand it there are two main methods to do this: Bluetooth and WiFi. However I wanted to know if anyone knows of any other way of sharing information between two iPhones? If I were in an area with no WiFi or mobile signal, and couldn't use Bluetooth for whatever reason, is there anything that could be done to broadcast data from one iPhone to another?

I'm sure its a bit of a silly question, but if you don't ask, you don't get; and if someone knows of anything I might be able to look into with regards to this, I would be very appreciative.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Wifi and Bluetooth are your only options for direct phone-to-phone communication.

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much what I thought, but didn't know if the iPhone had the capability of broadcasting a 'presence' that could be detected e.g. creating its own wireless network. Pretty far fetched maybe, but thought I'd ask :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse, there is still cellular data network because you are talking about the iPhone ;)

Comment: Indeed, but surely that wouldn't work in an area with no mobile coverage?